# No suitable driver found on attempt to connect Heroku Database using JDBC

Tags: java, postgresql, heroku, jdbc

I'm trying to connect my web app deployed in Heroku with the `postgre` database it offers.

I followed the instructions given at [this site](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/connecting-to-relational-databases-on-heroku-with-java) and deployed my app, but it threw the following error message

```
No suitable driver found for jdbc:postgresql://ec2-184-73-222-90.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5432/d9l4hq0c2h46o6?user=wyhgmwybghpndl&password=kWxLQ_y2risoVSFbzTKR_YsUFF&sslmode=require
```

I tried the suggestions given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14797896/no-suitable-driver-trying-to-connect-to-a-postgresql-database-on-heroku-using-h) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38981174/postgresql-jdbc-driver-not-working-for-heroku-db-connection), but didn't work.
I have ALSO added `postgresql-9.4.1211.jre6.jar` as External JARS in my buildpath.

Following is my **Test.java** that receives a `GET` request and tries to connect to Heroku database

```
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

@Path("wallpost")
public class wallpost {

    private static String connectionMsg = null;
    private static final String DATABASE_URL = "DATABASE_URL";
    private static final String JDBC_POSTGRE = "jdbc:postgresql://" ;
    private static final String JDBC_DATABASE_URL = "JDBC_DATABASE_URL"; 

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public  String getPosts() {

        Connection conn = null;
        try {
            conn = tryAndConnectToDB();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            connectionMsg = e.getMessage();
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            connectionMsg = e.getMessage();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if  (conn != null)
            try {
                return "Oops!! No posts made yet!!" + conn.getSchema();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return connectionMsg;
    }

    private static Connection tryAndConnectToDB() throws URISyntaxException, SQLException {

        try {
            Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
        } 
        catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {

            connectionMsg = e.getMessage();         
        }

        final String dbUrl = System.getenv(JDBC_DATABASE_URL);

            //URI dbURI = new URI(System.getenv(DATABASE_URL));

//          final String userName = dbURI.getUserInfo().split(":")[0];
//          final String userPassword = dbURI.getUserInfo().split(":")[1];
//          
//          final String dbURL = JDBC_POSTGRE + dbURI.getHost() + ":" + dbURI.getPort() + dbURI.getPath();

        //  return DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL,userName,userPassword);

        return DriverManager.getConnection(dbUrl);


        }

    }
```

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Did `Class.forName` successfully load the driver class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you need to reset your database credentials because you've posted them publicly. Run this command:

```
heroku pg:credentials DATABASE --reset
```

That error message suggests that you do not have the Postgres JDBC driver on your classpath.

The `postgresql-9.4.1211.jre6.jar` almost certainly not the JAR you want. It's for Java 6. And you don't want to make it an external dependency.

In your `pom.xml`, you should have this:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
  <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
  <version>9.4-1211</version>
</dependency>
```